# How to implement "value can only be inserted through view"?

Tags: mysql, view, triggers, sql-insert

1. I have a table `student (sno, sname, ssex, sage, sdept)`, which means id, name, sex, age and department.
2. I create a view `st_cs_info` which contains students' info who major in 'CS'(Computer Science).

```sql
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS st_cs_info;
CREATE VIEW st_cs_info AS
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE sdept='CS';
```

---

3. Then I need to implement a feature that **only values of CS students can be inserted through this view**.
   I try to create a trigger but get an error like:

```
'study.st_cs_info' is not BASE TABLE
```

seems that create a trigger on views is illegal.
**Here is my trigger code**:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER st_cs_info_insert
AFTER INSERT ON st_cs_info
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.sdept != 'CS' THEN
    DELETE FROM student
    WHERE student.sno=new.sno;
  END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

**PS**: my MySQL version is `8.0.32`.

I want to implement **"only values of CS students can be inserted through this view"**.
Besides, I am not sure whether should I use trigger.

Comment: ' want to implement "only values of CS students can be inserted through this view"' - I have no idea what you mean by this please provide a worked example..nb yuu cannot insert via a view nor can you have a trigger on a view.

Comment: @P.Salmon if a view is updateable, then you can insert new tows through a view.

Comment: I think it's quite clear what is being asked (whether it can be accomplished is another matter): The OP wants to ensure that when new rows are added via the view that the `sdept` column will be constrained to have the value `'CS'`. What the OP seems to have tried is to create a trigger that would check the just-inserted row for validity and delete it if it not valid.

Answer (score 1):

I already know how to check the new row.
There is no need to create a trigger.
All I need to do is to use `WITH CHECK OPTION` when I create the view.

```sql
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS st_cs_info;
CREATE VIEW st_cs_info AS
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE sdept='CS'
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Then when I insert new row into the view：

- If `sdept` is not `'CS'`, then it will result in an error.

```sql
INSERT INTO st_cs_info(sno, sname, ssex, sage, sdept)
VALUES ('202113002', 'John', NULL, 20, 'IS');
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
CHECK OPTION failed 'study.st_cs_info'
```

- If `sdept` is `'CS'`, then it will work successfully.

```sql
INSERT INTO st_cs_info(sno, sname, ssex, sage, sdept)
VALUES ('202113004', 'Kate', NULL, 20, 'CS');
```